# One-dimensional matrix into two-dimensional matrix in matrix by formula or pivot (excel)

Tags: excel, pivot

I try to find a formula in excel to count specific constellations within a matrix. In the original table the constellations are within one line and I want to break this down into lines and rows.

Specifically I try to change this Matrix:

```
HeaderA1 HeaderA2 HeaderA3 HeaderB1 HeaderB2  
___x____ ___x____ ________ ___x____ ___x____  
________ ___x____ ___x____ ________ ___x____ etc.
```

Into this Matrix:

```
XXXXXXXX HeaderA1 HeaderA2 HeaderA3  
HeaderB1 ____1____ ___1____ ___0____  
HeaderB2 ____1____ ___2____ ___1____
```

This has given me quite a headache so far, I tried pivot tables and formulas, but I can't find a solution. Some push in the right direction would already be great.

Thanks!
Thomas